# Correct filepath for deployed war file to access another file in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, filepath

I deployed a .war file manually by copying into the webapps folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps
```

In this same webapps directory, I added a file called "`properties.txt`"

What is the correct filepath for my .war file to access the "`properties.txt`"?

Currently, my code is:

```
String path = "./properties.txt";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

But this currently leads to the error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\properties.txt (The system cannot
>   find the file specified)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @NicolasFilotto So since I launched my application by using Tomcat8.exe which is inside C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin, is this considered to be the default folder? What should my filepath be to access "properties.txt"?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thanks for this method.  But is it possible to access without add the path to the launch command?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Nice! I managed to find the exact path I was searching for by creating a new file and get its path.  Thanks.